# Gameobject doesn't active on mouse click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing a problem in unity3d what i'm doing there is a gameobject which is a simple cube and
it's attach with a component called `Material` which is in red color. Also there is a script attach to this
cube which is performing a event on left mouse click i.e it's change the color of material to green. The script
works fine but what i want in the scene there is a `canvas` `gameobject` which is default inactive. [image: Picture]I want to
active this gameobject when the material color is green or deactivate when the color is red. I'm using
a function called `GameObject.Find("Canvas")` but error is coming. Also i try to solve this problem by using tags with this canvas by calling this function `GameObject.FindWithTag("Canvas")` but nothing works. Same error is coming.

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Code:

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private bool check;


    void OnMouseDown() {


        if (!check) {

            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.green;


            GameObject.Find("Canvas").SetActive(true);

            check = true;

        } else if (check) {

            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = Color.red;

            check = false;

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GameObject.Find` does not work when the GameObject is disabled. From the screenshot in your question, the Canvas GameObject is disabled.

That's why you are getting: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Create a public variable for it and drag the Canvas there.

```
[SerializeField]
private bool check;

public GameObject myCanvas;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (!check)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        myCanvas.SetActive(true);
        check = true;
    }
    else if (check)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        check = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can inactive any gameobject but GameObject.FindWithTag will not work on Object that is hidden or Object that the parent is hidden. You need to get reference of the Object when it is active or do it like I did in my answer by dragging the reference into it.